# Selecting minimum valued element of nested list after sorting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to select the minimum value of a nested list of the second element (the float part).

Code

```
n=int(input("Enter the number: "))
arr=[[input(),float(input())] for _ in range(0,n)]
arr.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))
min_val=min(arr)
print(min_val)
```

Input

```
Enter the number: 3
arp
5
grp
4
drp
3
```

Output

```
['arp', 5.0]
```

Expected output

```
['drp',3.0]
```

Comment: The `min(..)` does not care about the key, it sorts the tuples like tuples are sorted *by default*.

Comment: Its a sorted list, just use the first element in it ... `arr[0]`

Comment: @PatrickArtner I intended to remove all the minimum elements off the list, that's the reason for it.

Comment: "remove all the minimum elements"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use min with key as Willem Van Onsem suggested and apply filter to your sequence:

```
arr=[("a",2),("b","5"),("c",1),("a",2),("b","5"),("c",1)]  
# get minimal value
min_val=min(arr, key= lambda x:(x[1],x[0]))
# filter all with 2nd element euqal to minimals 2nd elemenbt
withoutMin = filter(lambda x: x[1] != min_val[1], arr)

# or use equivalent list comp:
# without = [x for x in arr if x[1] != min_val[x]] 
print(arr)

print(withoutMin)
```

Output:

```
[('a', 2), ('b', '5'), ('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', '5'), ('c', 1)]
[('a', 2), ('b', '5'), ('a', 2), ('b', '5')] # filtered
```

Answer (score 3):

You calculate the minimum with:

```
n = int(input("Enter the number: "))
arr = [[input(),float(input())] for _ in range(0,n)]
arr.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))
min_val=min(arr)
print(min_val)
```

This means that you will perform a loop over the list, and obtain the smallest element. Since you did not provide a key, Python will sort, like it sorts tuples by default: first by first element, and in case of a tie by second element and so on.

In case you want the minimum according to a specific key, you need to use the `key` parameter *of the `min` function*:

```
n = int(input("Enter the number: "))
arr = [[input(),float(input())] for _ in range(0,n)]
min_val=min(arr, key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))
print(min_val)
```

Note that obtaining the *minimum* is usually faster than *sorting* the list. If you do not need to sort the list, you can drop it, and simply use `min(..)` (like here).

In case you need to sort the list anyway, the smallest element is the first element of the list, so you can obtain it with:

```
n = int(input("Enter the number: "))
arr = [[input(),float(input())] for _ in range(0,n)]
arr.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))
min_val=arr[0]
print(min_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

since the array is already sorted:

```
print(arr[0])
```

OR

```
min_val=min(arr)
```

will sort by the first element. To sort by second element, change it to:

```
min_val=min(arr, key = lambda t: t[1])
```